# How to plot a vector field with error ellipse using cartopy

Tags: cartopy

Cartopy seems like a great tool for Geoscience, but it appears to lack a method for plotting vector data on a map together with their error ellipses.  Is there a straightforward way to add error ellipses centered on the tips of vector data?

Answer (score 0):

Cartopy inherits all its vector plotting functionality from matplotlib. Cartopy provides a way to project the vectors, but they are drawn by matplotlib. I haven't heard of a feature you describe in matplotlib, so I'm afraid the answer is probably no.